# boot script for linux EC2

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, docker

I have RHEL 7.5 Linux EC2 machine.It has below userdata.

```
#cloud-config
rumcmd:
- hostname "2CPV-PQ-XX6901"
- echo "2CPV-PQ-XX6901" > /etc/hostname
- authconfig --update --disablesssd --disablesssdauth --disablemkhomedir
- echo "sudo /root/init_bootstrap.sh > /root/init_boot.log 2>&1" | at -m now + 8 minute
- service restart sshd
```

I want to run below two commands automatically on reboot

```
 sudo HTTPS_PROXY= http://someproxy.xxx.com:8080 dockerd &
 sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock
```

I have added the above commands in /etc/rc.local but when i reboot it looks like it doesn't run the command as docker is not working.

Please suggest where i can provide these two commands so that docker deamon runs automatically on every reboot.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run `docker` on boot your best bet is using the official package that comes with the ready to use *systemd files*.

Something like this should do:

```
export https_proxy=http://someproxy.xxx.com:8080

yum-config-manager --add-repo https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo

yum install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
```

Now you have to set the proxy in the systemd docker config:

```
mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
cat > /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf << __EOF__
[Service]
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=${https_proxy}"
Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=${https_proxy}"
Environment="NO_PROXY=169.254.169.254,169.254.170.2"
__EOF__
```

You should also add the `ec2-user` to the `docker` group, then you won't need to change the `/var/run/docker.sock` permissions:

```
usermod -a -G docker ec2-user
```

All that can be done from the *EC2 User Data* script. In fact the above is a copy and paste from one of mine templates.

Then reboot and it should all work as expected.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: my shops restrictions prevent me from using yum and hence i have installed docker using binaries.